# a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific objectC/C++(245)

Tags: c++, constants

I have the following class declaration:

```
#ifndef ANIL_GRAPH_H
#define ANIL_GRAPH_H

#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include "anil_cursor_list.h"

namespace anil {
  class graph {
    private:

      // Data:
      cursor_list** vertices; // An array of cursor_lists whose ith element contains the neighbors of vertex i.
      int* vertex_color;  // An array of int whose ith element is the color (white, gray, black) of vertex i.
      int* vertex_predecessor; // An array of ints whose ith element is the parent of vertex i.
      int* vertex_distance; // An array of ints whose ith element is the distance from the most recent source to vertex i.
      int no_of_vertices; // The number of vertices (called the order of the graph).
      int no_of_edges;  // The number of edges (called the size of the graph).
      int most_recent_source_for_BFS; // The label of the vertex that was most recently used as a source for BFS.

      // Functions:
      void delete_graph();

    public:

      // Data:
      enum vertex_color_constants {
        WHITE = -3,
        GRAY,
        BLACK
      };

      const int INFINITY = -1;
      const int UNDEFINED_SOURCE = -1;
      const int UNDEFINED_PREDECESSOR = -1;

      // Functions:
      graph(int no_of_vertices);
      bool is_empty();
      int order_of_graph();
      int size_of_graph();
      int source_vertex();
      int parent_vertex(int child_vertex);
      int distance_to_source(int vertex);
      void path_from_source(cursor_list& path_list, int vertex);
      void delete_edges();
      void add_edge(int vertex_u, int vertex_v);
      void add_arc(int vertex_u, int vertex_v);
      void BFS(int source_vertex);
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, graph& rhs); // rhs = right hand side
      ~graph();
  };
}

#endif /* ANIL_GRAPH_H */
```

As you can see, inside the class declaration I have a couple of `const int` declarations which I use inside the implementation without any problems; however, when I try to use them inside my unit tests I get the error which is shown in the title of this question.

An example of a unit test in which I try to access `UNDEFINED_SOURCE`:

```
    case GRAPH_CONSTRUCTOR:
      {
        // Test to construct a graph.
        if (verbose) {
          os << "\nGRAPH_CONSTRUCTOR:" << std::endl <<
            "Starting the construction operation:" <<
            std::endl;
        }
        anil::graph my_graph(6);
        if (my_graph.order_of_graph() != 6 &&
            my_graph.size_of_graph() != 0 &&
            my_graph.source_vertex() != anil::graph::UNDEFINED_SOURCE) {
          if (verbose) {
            os << "Construction unsuccessful!" << std::endl;
          }
          return false;
        } else {
          if (verbose) {
            os << "Construction successful!" << std::endl;
          }
          return true;
        }
        return false;
        break;
      }
```

Can someone let me know how I can use the constants that I define inside the graph class without causing compilation errors?

Comment: Presumably, just make those constants `static` members (add that keyword to the declarations). I assume their values will be the same for all instances of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make it `static constexpr`

The issue is, without static you define a instance-specific variable that is not accessible without having a class instance.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Regarding constexpr: You can also make it `static const int` but then you might have to put the definition into your cpp file. So declare it in the header and define in cpp (due to memory address / one definition rule)

Comment: Just using this `static constexpr int UNDEFINED_SOURCE = -1;` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `my_graph.UNDEFINED_SOURCE` or declare as static member

The error states that because you don't have a static member, this member should be called by an object.

as in here:

```
#include <iostream>

class Example {
 public:
  const int my_const = 1;
  static const int my_static_const = 2;

};

int main() {
  Example a;
  std::cout << a.my_const << std::endl;
  std::cout << Example::my_static_const << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation :)